# How do I "bundle" my Google Analytics websites for /language/en?

Tags: url, google-analytics

I have a website which has only one language, English.
In Google Analytics, I get two different types of URLs, which makes my results harder to analyse:

"/screen/page/obd-ii-pid-examples/language/en"
"/screen/page/obd-ii-pid-examples"

I would like to somehow "aggregate"/bundle these together so e.g. #hits becomes the sum of the two types across my various URLs.

Is this possible somehow?

Best,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do would be to apply some filters to the view you are using
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en

A search and replace filter on /language/en would do the trick.